# Определить причину падения приложения без отладки

Tags: java, android

Приложение протестировано на большом количестве девайсов, но у клиента на его телефоне падает приложение при запуске. В проекте используется HockeyApp Bug Tracker, но даже он не успевает инициализоваться и отправить отчет. Отладить приложение соотвествено мы тоже не можем по причине того что клиент находится далеко, а как Вы поступаете в таких ситуациях? Хотелось бы услышать Ваше мнение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Попробовать другой *ловитель крашей*, например [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)
2. Попробовать провести удаленную отладку: [Так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp), или погуглить по запроссу `adb remote debug`
3. Купить такой же дивайс, как у клиента.
4. Указать тут, что у клиента за дивайс. Есть проблеммные дивайсы, возможно кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с проблемой определенного дивайса.
5. Уточнить, оригинальная ли прошивка установлена у клиента. Есть ли у него Google Play Services?